# Showing shrinkage with a plot for the interaction coefficient in a mixed-model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am trying to illustrate shrinkage in linear mixed models in a `2x2` factorial design. I would like to show the shrinkage effect for all coefficients including the interaction coefficient. However, I am unsure whether my approach is right. Here is what I did:

I fitted a linear-mixed model using `lmer()` from `lme4`. It is a complex model of the form:

```
 mod1 <- lmer(Val ~ Class * Complex
              + (Class * Complex | Subject)
              + (Class * Complex | Word),
              data = Lex)
```

I used contrast coding in order to see main effects in the model output:

```
contrasts(Lex$Class) <- contr.sum(2)
contrasts(Lex$Complex) <- contr.sum(2)
```

I then fit individual models per `Subject` and extract the coefficients:

```
df <- coef(lmList(Val ~  Class * Complex | Subject,
           data = Lex))
```

Then I extract the coefficients per `Subject` from the mixed-model:

```
cc1 <- as.data.frame(coef(mod1)[["Subject"]])
```

And bind it all together in a data frame:

```
names(cc1) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
df <- cbind(df, cc1)
```

I then go on to plot the `(Intercept)` per subject on the y-axis and the corresponding (slope-) coefficient on the x-axis for both: the individual models (purple) and the mixed-model (blue). However, I am unsure if this is correct for the interaction coefficient:

[image: Correct way to show shrinkage for the interaction coefficient?]

Comment: This looks reasonable at first glance, but (1) I don't quite understand your last sentence (" However, I am unsure if this is correct for the interaction coefficient:" -- please expand/clarify?) (2) Any chance of a reproducible example?

Comment: Of course I can add a reproducible example. Here is a gist on github: https://gist.github.com/03ed993441f8574c5858.git or https://gist.github.com/brauner/03ed993441f8574c5858. The data frame is `2060x5` and it needs to be because otherwise this rather complex model would not converge! Regarding my last sentence: I am unsure whether it makes sense to plot `per-item-intercept ~ per-item-interaction-coefficient` to illustrate the shrinkage for the interaction coefficient. The reproducible example should help to clarify this.